# ImageMagick php imagick loading a file from memory

Tags: imagemagick, imagick

I m trying to integrate imagick into my framework. The framework has the file in memory.

The imagick code works great

```
/* Read page 1 */
$im = new imagick( 'test.pdf[0]' );

/* Convert to png */
$im->setImageFormat( "png" );

/* Send out */
header( "Content-Type: image/png" );
echo $im;
```

Now my problem is imagick constructor takes only path name. How can i load the pdf from memory.

```
like $im = newImagick($file);
```

Comment: I got this far: /* Read page 1 */
$handle = fopen('test.pdf', 'rb');
$im2 = new Imagick();
$im2->readImageFile($handle);

/* Convert to png */
$im2->setImageFormat( "png" );

fclose($handle);
/* Send out */
header( "Content-Type: image/png" );
echo $im2;

Answer (score 5):

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImageBlob($file_contents);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-readimageblob.php